# How to execute two function one by one in the list of functions in the script.sh file

Tags: bash, shell, loops, switch-statement, sh

**I want two functions called one by one in a single bash command.**

1. I tried by calling in bash
2. ./script run delete_code run stop_node_pool - But it executes first function and stops. second function was not started.
3. ./script delete_code - If we give one function name its work for a particular function. But I need to call two functions that I choose while executing the script in bash.
4. How to write a program for executing any two functions one by one in a list of functions available in the script.sh file.

**My sample code**

```
#!/bin/bash
   
    
    delete_code() { 
    echo "code deleted"
    $1 && shift && "@a"
    }
    
    create_code() { 
    echo "code created"
    $1 && shift && "@a"
            }
    
    stop_node_pool() { 
    echo "node pool stopped"
    $1 && shift && "@a"
    }
    
    start_node_pool() { 
    echo "node pool start"
    $1 && shift && "@a"
    }

EXECUTION 
case $1 in
    delete_code) "$@"; exit;;
    create_code) "$@"; exit;;
    stop_node_pool) "$@"; exit;;
    start_node_pool) "$@"; exit;;

esac

delete_code
create_code
stop_node_pool
start_node_pool
```

Comment: no, my ask is very simple from the above function every time any two functions need to executives while calling the script.sh file.

Comment: ./script delete_code;  ./script stop_node_pool or add a second parameter ($2) and use it to call second function: ./script delete_code stop_node_pool

Comment: Your question is very unclear I'm afraid. Can you be specific about what you want to do. "Execute two functions only at a time" is too confusing. An example of the desired process/output would be good.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your problem (your question is confusing) but perhaps this will solve your issue:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 <code_deleted|code_created|node_pool_stopped|node_pool_start>" 1>&2; exit 1; }

# unless there are 2 arguments, print the "usage" and exit
[ ! $# -eq 2 ] && usage

# Functions
delete_code() {
    echo "code deleted test"
}

create_code() {
    echo "code created test"
}

stop_node_pool() {
    echo "node pool stopped test"
}

start_node_pool() {
    echo "node pool start test"
}

# Execution
for i in "$@"
do

    case "$i" in

        code_deleted)
            delete_code &
            ;;

        code_created)
            create_code &
            ;;

        node_pool_stopped)
            stop_node_pool &
            ;;

        node_pool_start)
            start_node_pool &
            ;;

        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
wait
```

Comment: This implies that the OP indeed want to create and delete **simultaneously**. While this could be the case (since the OP wrote "at a time"), we can't say for sure. The whole question is so confusing and ill-worded, that IMO no reasonable answer can be given, unless the question iteself is improved.

Comment: Oh yeah - I didn't think of it like that - I don't really know what OP wants - I spent 10 mins on it though, so I figured I should post an answer in case it helps, but I suspect it will be closed unless additional details are given.

Comment: My suggestion: If I spend more than a few minutes just understanding the sentences of a question on the English language level, I vote for closing the question. Being not a native English speaker myself, I have sympathy for people who can't write an understandable sentence, but at least one can write code, which shows the script which is called, and how the script is invoked, and what effect the invocation is expected to have. Scripts are programs and independent on the mother language.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, definitely ill improve my communication better next time, but the above answer works for me, thanks to jared_mamrot.

Comment: As per the above code both functions running parallelly, so I did a small correction. Now it works well Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 <code_deleted|code_created|node_pool_stopped|node_pool_start>" 1>&2; exit 1; }

# unless there are 2 arguments, print the "usage" and exit
[ ! $# -eq 2 ] && usage

# Functions
delete_code() {
    echo "code deleted test"
}

create_code() {
    echo "code created test"
}

stop_node_pool() {
    echo "node pool stopped test"
}

start_node_pool() {
    echo "node pool start test"
}

# Execution
for i in "$@"
do

    case "$i" in

        code_deleted)
            delete_code &
            ;;

        code_created)
            create_code &
            ;;

        node_pool_stopped)
            stop_node_pool &
            ;;

        node_pool_start)
            start_node_pool &
            ;;

        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
wait
done
```